# Is it possible to pass a Groovy closure defined as a variable to a function for execution, with another variable as part of the passed call?

Tags: groovy, closures, higher-order-functions

As the title says, if I define a closure that takes one argument can I pass it with an argument to be executed.

For example:

```
def print = { String NAME -> println "$NAME"}
```

And then pass it to another function for execution like this:

```
otherFunction(print("Jeff"))
```

If the other function has signature:

```
otherFunction(Closure clos):
    clos.call()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the call otherFunction( print("Jeff") ) is that you pass to it the return value of print("Jeff"), which is null because println does not return anything (void function).

Instead of this, you must pass the closure object which is layzy called with the method call(). You figured out yourself this, but my approach is more straightforward. Other solution would be to use [function composition](https://groovy-lang.org/closures.html#_composition):

```
def print = { println it }

def otherFunction(Closure clos) {
    clos.call()
}

// this is equivalent with otherFunction(null)
//otherFunction( print("Jeff") )

// pass a closure object
otherFunction { print("Jeff") }

// using function composition
def printJeff = print << { "Jeff" }
printJeff()
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I think I will rewrite my solution using your method. Answer accepted.

Answer (score 3):

I have figured out where I went wrong, I need my function to return a closure with my variable interpolated.

For example:

```
def Closure print (String NAME){
   {name -> println name}
}
```

Then make a call to generate a custom closure and pass that:

```
otherFunction(print("Jeff"))
```

Answered my own question please close.

Comment: SO encourages adding (and also accepting) your own answer. No need to close it.